# changing background color of a list view

Tags: android

can anyone help me with changing the background color of a list view?. I am new to android and I really need to know this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit so the text isn't all in a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setBackgroundColor() method of the ListView.

Comment: but this method has a int argument. and the color numbers are started from #. and it gives an error.

Comment: In code the color values can be given in hex format, too, but simply replace # with 0x.

Comment: You can also use the Color class to set the color:
setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

would this help for example:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/rssListView"
    android:background="#7700CC00"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

?

Comment: actually i have created a list in Java Android. and i want to change the background color through Java code.