# How to populate listview with "dynamic" video files in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

So far i have search online its rather filled with mostly hard-coding of strings to populate the listview which is not what i wanted. But instead i wanted to populate the listview with video file name or strings

[Here][1] is a tutorial based on music files is there any relevance in this link that i could extract in here that could populate my listview with video file instead of music file?

Comment: Here's and example that i use myself. From the example, basically you use and adapter "OrderAdapter" with "convertView" Objects that hold your data.  

[link](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments) 'Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters'

Comment: @Erik But the link you provide rather is it only designated for two files only but video files rather increase/decrease with respect to time how should i handle this "dynamic" presence in the code? And rather how should i retrieve my video file string and populate it into the listview? Sorry if i happen to ask stupid question here, i'm kinna bad in programming... :(

Comment: I realize maybe that was rather advanced if your just started learning. Im posting an answer with a complete example not using threads like this does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice example using an Adapter

[Displaying the List of music files Stored in SD card and playing music in the background](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html)

Comment: @Erik i have tried this link you just gave me but i instead opt for the link you given me earlier but i am pose with the problem how am i going to populate my listview with rather "dynamic" video string rather than fixed with 2 file object.. Could you tell me what are areas i should tweak in the code in order to do that?

Comment: Did you try this example?  If you debug it you'll see that ..init_phone_music_grid() is the methid you need to modify

Comment: @Erik So you mean i should be doing the example for init_phone_music_grid() rather than the earlier link you gave me? Or do you mean init_phone_music_grid() is the part i need to put into the earlier example to do exactly that of a dynamic video list string? Sorry if i'm slow in understanding questions..

Comment: In this(ANSWER) example:
Change all MediaStore.Music.Media to MediaStore.Video.Media.
That will show a list of all videos on your phone, and you can play them

Comment: @Erik I'm confuse... So should i go with my own version of code i coded above, or follow http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments or http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html ?? And my lecturer insisted me to code with ListActivity rather than Activity as seen in the example...

Comment: softwarepassion is using the listActivity and if your lecture tell you to use it you should of cource!. 
I think you should start to learn how ListActivity and ListView works. The two examples we talked about both do what you want in different ways. Regarding your level of experience i suggest you follow this nice tutorial from Lars Vogel
  
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

When finish the tutorial im sure you get a pretty good ide what you have to do

Comment: @Erik The tutorial you offering still seems to be "hard-coding" of strings? So the code for retrieving "dynamic-strings" is still found init_phone_music_grid() isn't it? Then the main source code i should be taking reference for is softwarepassion?

Comment: @Erik Or is it possible to take a hybrid of between both to accomplish the task i mention?

Comment: yes a hybrid is possible
This example(one in many) load files from SDCARD and extract the "String" name of the files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895104/file-browser-in-android

Comment: @Erik Hi i have done little bit of modification to my above codes but or rather now i'm faced with how am i going to change the feel and look similar to the one in softwarepassion using OrderAdapter.. Can you help? Sorry if i'm rather slow in my learning progress...

Comment: This is a new question! You should ask a new question.
Btw this question already has an/many answer. like his one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298939/changing-background-color-of-a-list-view

Comment: @Erik Ok i will post the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931483/how-to-create-my-above-listview-to-look-more-professional but at the same time i wanted to ask you how am i going to remove the .mp4 or .3gp at the end of the file name caused by this statement "videoItems.add(file.getName());"