# How to create my above listview to look more professional?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Can someone tell me how should am i going to create my listview which look similar [here][1].

Problem: How am i going to fulfill the sort of look and feel in my codes which has an icons, file name, and file size yet at the same time looking clean and simple on each file object as shown in the example in the link [here][2]??

Can someone guide on this matter because i'm rather new in android/java... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to following [url for how to implement custom listview](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)

**Update**

```
public static class VideoInfo   {
        public String name = "";
        public String size= "";
        public String path = "";//add any more variables of which you want info
    }
```

then where you are creating arraylist i.e `getVideoFiles()` create object of this class 
Declare `ArrayList<VideoInfo> videoItems;`

```
private void getVideoFiles(File[] videoList) 
 {
      videoItems = new ArrayList<VideoInfo>();

      for (int i = 0; i < videolist.length; i++) 
      {
        File mfile = videoList[i];
      String path = mfile.getPath();
      path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/", path.indexOf("."));
      VideoInfo model = new VideoInfo();
      model.name = path;
      model.size = mfile.length();

      videoItems.add(model);
      }

      setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row, videoItems));  
 }
```

now in your adapter pass this object of arraylist and how you set variables in listview is already given in link above

Comment: @T0X1C Hello could you recommend how the above set of answers could help me to solve my problem here where i tried using HERO answer but not knowing what needs to be tweak to made it work --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933657/how-to-create-a-listview-which-have-a-customize-look

Comment: @T0X1C Hi could tell me how can i get my video file name to populate my textview above for my codes above?? And how can i remove my .mp4 and .3gp string at the back of these strings?

Comment: @T0X1C updated above but why is there still errors everywhere have i done something wrong?

Comment: Look I have given a general idea and to very specific to your problem more than neither or nobody here can help you you have to slove problems yourself as they might be related to some tit bits of java language

Comment: @T0X1C sorry if i ask too much, because i'm rather very poor in programming and to make it worse i'm rather new to android/java and running a a very short time to finish this project in 2 weeks.. :(

Comment: no problem thats happens to everybody but truth is you have to solve most of the problems by yourself and if you have any specific problem then you are most welcome

Comment: @T0X1C after trying the whole morning i still don't know how to implement your codes? Name: "empty", File Size: "empty" all these parameters still remain empty..

Comment: I have updated the answer check that and I suggest you that study the code that is given url or you will not be able to get it

Comment: @T0X1C why is new File(videofile[i]); error message: videofile cannot be resolved as a variable?

Comment: @T0X1C  File mfile = videofile[i];
       String path = videofile[i]; Both still have the same error for "cannot be resolved as a variable"?

Comment: @T0X1C videoItems = new ArrayList<VideoInfo>();   File mfile = File(videoList[i]);
      String path = videoList[i]; these statement still having errors...

Comment: @T0X1C videoItems = new ArrayList<VideoInfo>(); --> cannot covert from Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ListViewActivity.VideoInfo> to ArrayList<Object> mfile.length(); -- >Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to String

Comment: I told you to change ArrayList<Object> as ArrayList<VideoInfo> videoItems

Comment: @T0X1C Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to String --> cannot convert from long to String

Comment: @@T0X1C model.size = String.valueOf(mfile.length()); ok solved

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 2: And why is my listview
>   having error when the directory is
>   empty despite having this to handle
>   the "empty" in my xml

did you remember to name your listview?:

```
@id/android:list
```

And if you could for further helper **PLEASE clear up problem 1**, so its more clear and concise what you want.

**UPDATE**

The ID of the listview should be: `@id/android:list`

The ID of the texview should be: `@id/android:empty`

Comment: @JoxTraex i have did some editing but i still don't quite know how to solve Problem 1 and 2? can you help?

Comment: @JoxTraex Still having error despite the changes made. It will be ok when the directory is not empty but when the directory is empty it gives nullpointer... Shouldn't the textview be shown instead? What's the problem here?

Comment: Please update your post with the modifications that you've made. Also post your logcat if there is a crash.

Comment: @JoxTraex updated:Sorry first time posting logcat, took me some time to figure it out..

Comment: @JoxTraex Problem 2 solved.. But could you help me pertaining to problem 1? I really have no idea how to get the sort of looks and layout seen in this link http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments

Comment: @JoxTraex Can you help? On the matter on how to integrate the code suggested by T0X1C into my codes to display string/length more dynamically? I really have no idea how to do so.... :(

Comment: @Vivian Join the Android Assistance chat channel and I'll help you for a bit.

Comment: @JoxTraex May i ask how to join?

Comment: @Vivian hit 'chat' at the top and then look up the room 'Android Assistance'

Answer (score 0):

You haven't create custom adapter to incorporate the layout into codes listview.
Here is something you can use

```
private class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
        private ArrayList<Object> items;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Object> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            Object info = items.get(position);
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            if (info != null) {
                ImageView imView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                TextView txtname =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView txtAddr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                //set image and set text as you like
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering do i just copy the codes into my codes and it will work just fine or there's some tweaking/modification to do to make it work?

Comment: why after implementing your code the icon seems to fill up the entire display screen? Is there something i have done wrong here in my codes above?

Answer (score 0):

First Create the Layout that you want to display for each row in your list then Extend the BaseAdapter class to Customize your Lists. This class contains getView method to replicate the rows in your lists as many times as you want to.

class HighScoreAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
/* layout inflater to convert your XML layout to View to be rendered in your Each row of Lists.*/
        private LayoutInflater minflator    =   LayoutInflater.from(HighScoreList.this);
        ViewHolder holder;

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    boolean toRemove = false;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
                    /* first time is null */
        if (convertView == null )
        {
            convertView = minflator.inflate(R.layout.highscorelist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rank = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
            holder.username = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_nameedit);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_time);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder  =   (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position+1)+".");

        /* returns the view for next row as layout will be same i.e. this increases the your list's scrolling and working faster even though your list contains thousands of Entry*/
        return convertView;
    }
             /* this class is to make reference to your child views of your layout by using this you can set your child views properties and Listeners acording to your need.*/
    class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView rank;
        EditText username;
        TextView time;
    }

}
```

I hope this solves your problem completely.. :)

Comment: @Deepak Sharma hi thanks for answering but which of the set of answers is best suited for my case?

Comment: thanks for asking to me .. the way i have told you and one described by @HERO are very much similar i have enhanced it littile bit more .. as you have to register listener on each row of your list or child view of Lists (i think you will surely want to implement some functionality like clicking on file plays some audio or something else functionality) .. don't extend to ListActivity until and unless your screen contains only lists..i hope now this clears your doubt.. :)

Comment: @Deepak Sharma Can you help me a bit, because i show the series of between yours and HERO to my lecturer and he told me to use his as "reference" without telling me how to implement HERO's code into my code... :( Can me tell me how? Updated above but its not working?

Comment: @Deepak Sharma Can you help? Because i don't really know what i should modify in my codes to make it work with "reference" to HERO's example?

Comment: can you tell me what info you are getting in your items arraylist i.e. what i guess is you are getting only path of your files stored .. do u want to display only those .. reply me back as sson as possible:)

Comment: I'm rather retrieving something like video string where the application is rather similar to the link here --> http://www.google.com.sg/imglanding?q=autoguard+blackbox&hl=en&sa=X&tbm=isch&prmd=ivns&tbnid=CQTLl4767M6hpM:&imgrefurl=http://droidmill.com/autoguard-pro-124459.html&imgurl=http://cdn1.droidmill.com/media/market-media/com.hovans.autoguard.key_1.png&w=480&h=854&ei=Xb3HTYKjH4eJrAebnuzlBA&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=173&tbnw=97&start=0&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0&biw=1366&bih=653, where it shows three stages after each click in the file object it displays the custom dialog and give user to choose

Comment: @Deepak Sharma description above, adding somemore detail i only wanted to display the name of the file, file size and icon on each so called file object..

Comment: then run the HERO's code and add one or three line in the code.

Comment: @Deepak Sharma but it don't seems to work like it should be it terms of the format above or have i not added something something to make it work properly? Sorry i'm rather new to android/java..

Comment: @Deepak Sharma I don't quite get you what should i change in my code to display the icon, name of file and file size with respect to the two Textview in the xml file? Or i have to do some other modification to allow the layout to work? I have encounter this link here http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments but i have really no idea how to use the context here in this link to populate a rather more "dynamic" listview?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your code and if you get any error or Exception please let me know.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Object info = items.get(position);
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        if (info != null) {
            ImageView imView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtname =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView txtAddr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
            //set image and set text as you like

               imview.setImageBitmap(IMAGE YOU WANT TO SET AAS ICON);

               txtname.setText(FILENAME YOU WANT TO SET);

               txtadr,setText(FILESIZE YOU WANT TO SET);

              // Better you take each info filename,filesize and icon in a arraylist and set them 

        }


        return v;
    }
```

Comment: @Deepak Sharma i have done exactly what you said and although the app run but unfortunately it displays a big icon which covers almost the entire display screen instead of thing shown here --> http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-3/#comments or is there some sort of size comparison i have to make as seen in the link?? If it is so is there a simpler way to code it because i don't get what the code is saying... :(

Comment: @Deepak Sharma why is my icon image covering the entire display screen?

Comment: @Deepak Sharma another question of mine which is how do i get the Name  which removes the ".mp4" or ".3gp" behind each strings of my video file name? Which means this statement is use now? for (File file : videoList) 
          {
            videoItems.add(file.getName());
          }

Comment: Don't use android:layout_height="fill_parent" for ImageView in your row.xml instead of this use android:layout_height="wrap_content"..

Comment: @Deepak Sharma So i can actually remove "ImageView imView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);" and "imview.setImageBitmap(IMAGE YOU WANT TO SET AAS ICON);" right because the xml will instead handle the icon?

Comment: @Deepak Sharma Can you tell me how to populate my textview with more dynamic name and how to get to remove the ".3gp" and ".mp4" string at the back of each string?