# How to create the above custom dialog in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog

Can someone tell me how to create the above dialog view similar/exactly to the link [here][1], whereby the focus of the problem is to create the view in the centre of the picture?

I have done some research and it made me wonder should i be using a custom xml to create a custom dialog view or should i be using alertdialog to create the exact view programmability shown above? And even if alertdialog is possible how am i going to accommodate with so many textview messages shown in the middle of the dialog picture given alertdialog limitation? Eg: "builder.setMessage("This is the alert's body");" If you know what i mean!!

Can someone tell me the easiest way to get the exact same view because i'm kinna doing the same app and new to android.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach will be custom dialog. As it will be helpful creating all those background colours and the effect. I am sure the link you have posted is using custom dialog as well,

cheers

link that might help:

[1] http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

[2] http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/creating-custom-dialog-in-android.html

/// In your code implementations just add this code when you create dialog....after having this just have all TextView arranged in your layout and add that layout id to this below code good luck

```
//Dialog box creator
private Dialog constructYourDialog()
{
    //Preparing views
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.***your_xml_name***, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.***Yout view id***));
    //Building dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Show Videos", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.i("","Show Video Click");
                dialog.dismiss();
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("E-Mail", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Log.i("","E-mail Click");
           dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
     builder.setNeutralButton("Show Map", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i("","Show Map Click");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    return alert;

}
```

Comment: i have updated a xml file above which i tried but its not showing the dialog view i intended! Can you tell me what i should code in my current xml do get the appropriate view seen in the link? I've have tried reading on android developer but still unable to get the xml layout view i intend to get, i'm rather new to android/xml can you help me on this matter?

Comment: but how should i modify/code my xml to look exactly the same as the link above.. Like the three button position, size and how to control the relative layout correct sizes and etc??

Comment: my code is generating three button and listeners...you just need to add your code about what you want your button to invoke inside those listeners. And regarding xml, I would prefer using eclipse it has graphical interface to drag and drop layout and align views.

Comment: i have edited a bit of my xml but the position of my button still does not aline the way it should have in the picture? Why is it so? And the title "Information" should it be done by xml through textview or should it to be done programmability to create the title sort of image feel?

Comment: the three button for u added in the java is not for xml button right?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Alert !");
builder.setMessage("your text here");
builder.setPositiveButton("Show Video", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        connect = false;
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Show Map", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
}
});
builder.setNeutralButton("Show Both", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
}
});
builder.show();
```

**UPDATE:** To show custom title create a layout and inflate it using below code

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
View layout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null);
```

Remove following line from above code

```
builder.setTitle("Alert !");
```

and then set using

```
builder.setCustomTitle(layout)
```

Comment: @T0X1C Hi the thing now i'm facing is to get the entire view of the custom dialog seen in the link rather than actual implementation of the buttons seen in the picture...

Comment: you mean to say the custom title bar?

Comment: @T0X1C So the entire view i see in that link is a custom title bar? If so how should i create the view??

Comment: @T0X1C ok before i proceed to do this question can you  answer the question in this link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931483/how-to-create-my-above-listview-to-look-more-professional Thanks

Comment: check answer of that question

Comment: @T0X1C can you tell me what's wrong with my custom dialog after some modification i made because it seems to be displaying two custom dialog despite dismissing the previous dialog? Updated my codes above

Comment: @T0X1C i don't quite get what you mean?

Comment: In your clicklistener of btnArcheive call dialog.dismiss(); before this line ArchiveFile();

Comment: @T0X1C i do not really add the statement dialog.dismiss()? Sorry for not being able to understand your question...

Comment: @T0X1C then what's the problem with my code above why is it  displaying two dialog box? And why my title look different as the link i provide?

Comment: @T0X1C yes but i am was told to do it in xml format by my lecturer that's why my code code turn out like that different from yours.. Sorry if i never follow your code example

Comment: It can not be dismessed from xml, aml is only for inflating the layout to show/hide that inflated layout you have to use code

Comment: @T0X1C so there is no reliable solution to my problem here where it displaying two dialog box overlaying?

Comment: only way is to "In your clicklistener of btnArcheive call dialog.dismiss(); before this line ArchiveFile();"

Comment: @T0X1C sorry if i cannot describe my problem well enough, after i have my custom dialog screen displayed, the problem arouse if i press phone's back button it "indeed" goes back but instead it display another small dialog box after exiting the previous custom dialog box?

Comment: @T0X1C by the way the problem sill persist after i implement your suggestion?

Comment: @Saurabh Agnihotri hi i have solve the problem of two dialog box... But do you have any idea how how i have the icon beside the title and why is my title looking kinna dull?