# How to create this particular dialog view in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create the above custom dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933003/how-to-create-the-above-custom-dialog-in-android)

Can someone tell me how to create the above dialog view similar/exactly to the link [here](http://www.google.com.sg/imglanding?q=autoguard%20blackbox&hl=en&sa=X&tbm=isch&prmd=ivns&tbnid=CQTLl4767M6hpM:&imgrefurl=http://droidmill.com/autoguard-pro-124459.html&imgurl=http://cdn1.droidmill.com/media/market-media/com.hovans.autoguard.key_1.png&w=480&h=854&ei=QJvMTY2HFoL8vQPx7-H5Bg&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=175&tbnw=98&start=0&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0&biw=1366&bih=653), whereby the focus of the problem is to create the view in the centre of the picture?

I have done some research and it made me wonder should i be using a custom xml to create a custom dialog view or should i be using alertdialog to create the exact view programmability shown above? And even if alertdialog is possible how am i going to accommodate with so many textview messages shown in the middle of the dialog picture given alertdialog limitation? Eg: "builder.setMessage("This is the alert's body");" If you know what i mean!!

Can someone tell me the easiest way to get the exact same view because i'm kinna doing the same app and new to android.. Thanks :)

**Updated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView1"/>
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button1" 
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:text="Exit" />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button2" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:text="Show Video" />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button3" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:text="Show Map" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Updated**

```
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#FFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView1"/>
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#FFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#FFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView2" />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button2" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Archive" />
    <Button 
    android:text="Show Video" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/Button1" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></Button>
    <Button 
    android:text="Show Map" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/Button2" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button2"
    ></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
```