# How to create a listview which have a customize look?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create my above listview to look more professional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931483/how-to-create-my-above-listview-to-look-more-professional)

Problem: How am i going to fulfill the sort of look and feel in my codes which has an icons, file name, and file size yet at the same time looking clean and simple on each file object as shown in the example in the link [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/)?? Can someone tell me how to incorporate the layout example into my codes listview?

Can someone guide on this matter because i'm rather new in android/java... Thanks

This is what i tried out so far and its not working...

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> videoItems = null;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.videolistview);

        File filePath = new File("/sdcard/Video_List");

        if(!(filePath.exists()))
        {
            filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Video_List");
            filePath.mkdir();
        }   
        getVideoFiles(filePath.listFiles());
     }

     private void getVideoFiles(File[] videoList) 
     {
          videoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

          for (File file : videoList) 
          {
            videoItems.add(file.getName());
          }

          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.row, videoItems)); 
     }

     @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
     {
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogBox.class));
     }
}
```

My row.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

UPDATED:

public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private ArrayList<Object> videoItems = null;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.videolistview);

    File filePath = new File("/sdcard/Video_List");

    if(!(filePath.exists()))
    {
        filePath.mkdir();
    }   
    getVideoFiles(filePath.listFiles());
 }

 private void getVideoFiles(File[] videoList) 
 {
      videoItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

      for (File file : videoList) 
      {
        videoItems.add(file.getName());
      }

      setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row, videoItems));  
 }

 private class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
 {
        private ArrayList<Object> items;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Object> items) 
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            Object info = items.get(position);
            if (info != null) {
                TextView txtName =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView txtVideoSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

                txtName.setText("Name: " + info.);    
                txtVideoSize.setText("Video Size: " + info.);
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
 {
     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogBox.class));
 }
```

}